# how to i have a printed line in the console EG:" I have <input> apples and <input> pears " and then the user can input values in that line?

Tags: python-3.x

lets say when the program starts, the user is printed a line where he/she can input 
values Eg:

I have    apples and I have    pears

and then the user can input values in both spaces, after both "have"

Answer (score 0):

A basic program to do this would be

```
input1 = input("Enter a fruit ") #Ask the user to input 
input2 = input("Enter another fruit") #then ask for another
str = "I have a(n) " #store the basic string (the 'n' is in brackets because we don't know if the user input will start with a vowel or not .. you can develop this later)
str = str + input_string1  + " and" + str + input_string2 #concatenate the lot
print("Output = ", str) #this will give you "Output = "(your sentence)
print(str) #or you could just print the string
```

Hope this helps

(this is code for, alternatively, accepting a list/splitting/using a for loop, but you would have to add more code to check for adding " and",  checking for vowels etc..)

```
input_string = input("Enter fruits separated by a comma ")
str = "I have a(n) "
fruit_list  = input_string.split(",")
#print out the result
for fruit in fruit_list:
   print(str + fruit )
```